# Peculiar Integral with Power Laws

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

I am trying to calculate the potential for a system of two non-linear coupled oscillators. To do that I would have to calculate the following integral:
\begin{equation}
V(x,y)=\alpha \int_{}|x|^{n-1}x dx+ \beta \int_{}|y-x|^{n-1}(y-x)dx, \quad \alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}
where $n \in [0,1]$.

Problem is I cannot really think of a way to analytically go throught with this integration. In fact, I am not even sure that there exists an analytical solution.
Any opinions?

Comment: What's the problem, these are mere powers. Are you worried about the absolute values ?

Comment: Are these supposed to be definite integrals or just antiderivatives?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yeap, how do you go throught the product of a variable with the absolute value of that variable on a power?

Comment: @MPW Just antiderivatives.

Comment: Rewrite $\pm x^n$, depending on the sign of $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Polynomials? I don't think so. Not only are there absolute values, but also $n$ needn't be integral, right?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Should I substitute $|x|^{n-1}$ with $sgn(x)^{n-1}$?

Comment: @MPW: I changed my comment.

Comment: @Mitscaype: surely not, $sgn$ is $\pm1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed my bad.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok, I started by taking cases for $x$, either $x>0$ or $x<0$. But what about the difference in the second integral? I should I take also into account if $y-x>0$ or $y-x<0$ and so on?

Comment: Yep,simple as that.

Comment: $x $ should not be both an input and your dummy variable of integration

Comment: @AndyWalls It is an indefinite integral therefore it does not play any role in this case.